# How can I load .bash_profile when calling Process.run?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to determine the location of the 'flutter' script on a user's computer using this Dart code:

```
Process.run('which', ['flutter'], runInShell: true).then((results) {
      print('which returned code ${results.exitCode}\n  StdOut: ${results.stdout}\n  StdErr: ${results.stderr}');
}
```

The problem is that the PATH environment has been set in the user's .bash_profile file like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/mr_pink/dev/flutter/bin
```

but apparently the .bash_profile script doesn't get loaded when I call Process.run.  How can I make sure it is loaded so that the "which flutter" command uses the correct PATH variable?

Comment: You can try running `bash -c flutter ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading `man bash` I found the solution was to add -l to the bash command like this:

```
Process.run('bash', ['-l', '-c', 'which flutter'])
```